# How to create a factor from a binary indicator matrix?

Tags: r

Say I have the following matrix `mat`, which is a binary indicator matrix for the levels `A`, `B`, and `C` for a set of 5 observations:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,0,0,
                1,0,0,
                0,1,0,
                0,1,0,
                0,0,1), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mat) <- LETTERS[1:3]

> mat
     A B C
[1,] 1 0 0
[2,] 1 0 0
[3,] 0 1 0
[4,] 0 1 0
[5,] 0 0 1
```

I want to convert that into a single factor such that the output is equivalent to `fac` defines as:

```
> fac <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = c(2,2,1)))
> fac
[1] A A B B C
Levels: A B C
```

Extra points if you get the labels from the colnames of `mat`, but a set of numeric codes (e.g. `c(1,1,2,2,3)`) would also be acceptable as desired output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Elegant solution with matrix multiplication (and shortest up to now):

```
as.factor(colnames(mat)[mat %*% 1:ncol(mat)])
```

Comment: `seq_len(ncol(mat))` would be more robust, but as your answer is simple, elegant *and* deals with the possibility of an unordered indicator matrix, you get the Accept. The ordering could easily be solved in the other solutions, but that will add to their length. Thanks Thomas.

Comment: @Gavin, thanks. Regarding robustness - how is seq_len more robust? You mean the case when ncol(mat) == 0? In that case it wouldn't work either.

Comment: I know, but `1:ncol(mat)` gives `1,0` in that case, and `seq_len(ncol(mat))` returns a zero length integer vector - which is the right answer. You could imagine cases where `1:ncol(mat)` might work but give the wrong answer whilst `seq_len(ncol(mat))` would cause it to fail appropriately. I'm just always wary of `1:foo` where `foo` is computed.

Comment: @Gavin, thanks, good note. But as I tested it now, you don't need to worry with `ncol()`. It seems it will never return something smaller than 1 without an error (which is quite expected behaviour).

Answer (score 8):

This solution makes use of the `arr.ind=TRUE` argument of `which`, returning the matching positions as array locations.  These are then used to index the `colnames`:

```
> factor(colnames(mat)[which(mat==1, arr.ind=TRUE)[, 2]])
[1] A A B B C
Levels: A B C
```

---

Decomposing into steps:

```
> which(mat==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   2   1
[3,]   3   2
[4,]   4   2
[5,]   5   3
```

Use the values of the second column, i.e. `which(...)[, 2]` and index `colnames`:

```
> colnames(mat)[c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)]
[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "C"
```

And then convert to a factor

Comment: Will not work if the factors are not ordered, try it on matrix `mat2 = rbind(mat, c(1, 0, 0))`.

Comment: The problem is that `which()` is doing it by columns, not by rows. You can fix it by transposing it (swapping rows/columns): `factor(colnames(mat2)[which(t(mat2)==1, arr.ind=TRUE)[,1]])`. I don't know, maybe there is a better way how to tell `which()` to go by rows, not by columns!

Comment: This can be overcome by taking its transpose: `rownames(which(t(mat2) == 1, arr.ind=T))` = `"A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A"`.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to replicate the names out by row number and index directly with the matrix, then wrap that with `factor` to restore the levels:

```
factor(rep(colnames(mat), each = nrow(mat))[as.logical(mat)])
[1] A A B B C
Levels: A B C
```

If this is from model.matrix, the colnames have `fac` prepended, and so this should work the same but removing the extra text:

```
factor(gsub("^fac", "", rep(colnames(mat), each = nrow(mat))[as.logical(mat)]))
```

Comment: Again, it will not work if the factors are not ordered, try it on matrix `mat2 = rbind(mat, c(1, 0, 0))`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
lvls<-apply(mat, 1, function(currow){match(1, currow)})
fac<-factor(lvls, 1:3, labels=colnames(mat))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one

```
factor(rep(colnames(mat), colSums(mat)))
```

Comment: Will not work if the factors are not ordered, try it on matrix `mat2 = rbind(mat, c(1, 0, 0))`.